# Absolutely positioned DIV inconsistent across browsers

Tags: css, debugging, cross-browser, positioning

I have a problem with an absolutely positioned DIV - it's not sitting in exactly the same spot across browsers.  The issue is that most of my content is being generated by a JSP file and I have to apply the CSS and create my content in a CMS, outside of this file. Here's how the code is structured:

```
                <div id="automatic-container">
                 <div class="one">
                 <div class="oneWeird"></div>
                 <div id="content-container">
                     <div id="some-content1"></div>
                     <div id="some-content2"></div>
                 </div>
                <div id="absolutely-position">plain text is inserted here via JSP file, wrapped only in div tags. adding/styling p tags does not help</div>  
                </div>
                </div>
```

Everything other than the "content-container" is automatically generated by a JSP file.  The content in the "absolutely-position" div should be laid on top of the content in "content container" and sit in a specific spot. oneWeird is a div being created by the JSP that seems to serve no purpose that I can tell...

I have applied the following CSS and the absolutely-position DIV is off by a few pixels in every browser (I checked Chrome, IE7,8,9, FF, Safari).  It matches in Chrome, Safari & IE8. In FF, it's about 3 pixels higher, IE 9 it's 5 pixels higher, and in IE7 it's dropped down by about 10 pixels.

```
                #automatic-container{position: relative; padding: 0px; margin: 0px auto;}
                #automatic-container div.one {position: relative; padding: 0px; margin: 0px auto;}
                #automatic-container div.one div.oneWeird{display: none;}
                #content-container{margin: 0px auto; width: 848px; height: 354px; background:url('bkg_confirm.jpg') no-repeat; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; position: relative; padding: 0;}
                #some-content1{position: relative; margin: 0px; text-align: center; padding: 0; width: 490px; height: 354px; left: 343px; top: 30px;}
                #some-content2 {position: relative; width: 490px; height: 55px; border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 0px; margin: 60px 0 0 0; overflow:hidden;}
                #absolutely-position{height: 20px; left: 420px; position: absolute; text-align: center;top: 125px; width: 465px;font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
```

Any ideas on how to get the absolutely position DIV consistent across browsers? None of the articles I've found on SO or elsewhere have been helpful. I have tried changing the positioning to relative and using z-index, but that also produced inconsistent results.  My code is clean when I run it through online validation as well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and I'll try to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or Normalize.css http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/ to your pages before applying your normal css. I almost gaurantee what you're running up against is the different default styles different browsers use.

What a reset does is sets all styles to a baseline before you start applying your own styles. So if Chrome applies x amount of margin to an element and IE applies Y amount the reset puts them both at 0. The downside is every element that you use has to be restyled. For example lists no longer have a default style, nor do block quotes etc.

Normalize.css is a little easier for newcomers to use because it sets base styles for everything much like a reset does but it gives most things a style rather than just setting them to 0, so your lists will still be indented with a bullet but they will look the same on all browsers (or should.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I used Meyer's reset as a starting point and edited so it would only affect the content within the CMS zone I'm working in.